# Pointer of structure initialization to NULL

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm having a problem with a structure within a structure:

```
typedef struct BrickStruct
{
    int type;
    SDL_Rect Brick_Coordinates;  
    SDL_Surface *Brick_Surface = NULL;  
}BrickStruct;
```

my compiler says that about the line with the `SDL_Surface` structure:

`error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token`

But I don't really understand because I got in front of me my teacher's lesson about pointer of structure saying that:
`Coordinate *point = NULL;`

Coordinate being a structure with two `int` inside: `int x,y;`

Can somebody explain me that weird thing ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't initialize a `struct`'s member in the `struct`'s declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C language does not allow for the initialization of instance fields inline like this.  The standard practice is to write a factory style method which does the initialization for you

```
BrickStruct create_brick_struct()
{
  BrickStruct s;
  s.Brick_Surface = NULL;
  s.type = <default type value>;
  s.Brick_Coordinates = <default coordinatos value>;
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, that's been really helpful and you took a weight off my mind. Since I already use a function to initialize my coordinates, I will initialize my surfaces at the same time.

To be real really clear: my structure will now looks like this, right ?:

```
typedef struct BrickStruct
{
    int type;
    SDL_Rect Brick_Coordinates;  
    SDL_Surface *Brick_Surface;   // I'm just wondering if I need to make it a pointer here 
}BrickStruct;
```